# How to make function return True if two functions and domains are same?

Tags: functions, function-construction

(Please see the edit part for the real problem)

I have two expressions which are same but written in different ways.

```
expr1 = ConditionalExpression[Plus[1, Times[-1, x]], 
  Inequality[0, LessEqual, x, LessEqual, Rational[1, 2]]]
```

[image]

```
expr2 = ConditionalExpression[Plus[1, Times[-1, x]], 
  LessEqual[0, x, Rational[1, 2]]]
```

[image]

Now if I use Equal function:

```
expr1 == expr2
```

[image]

It returns True together with domains combining of the two functions. However, I want it to return `True` only (no domain) if the functions are same and domains are same as well.
How can I do that? 
`SameQ` doesn't work here as they are same mathematically but the underlying representations are different.

**EDIT**:
Basically I have a list like this.

```
list = {ConditionalExpression[Plus[1, Times[-1, x]], 
   Inequality[0, LessEqual, x, LessEqual, Rational[1, 2]]], 
  ConditionalExpression[Plus[1, Times[-1, x]], LessEqual[1, x, 2]], 
  ConditionalExpression[Plus[1, Times[-1, x]], 
   LessEqual[0, x, Rational[1, 2]]]}
```

[image]

I want to return the position of elements in the list that same as reffunc as follows:

```
reffunc = 
  ConditionalExpression[Plus[1, Times[-1, x]], 
   LessEqual[0, x, Rational[1, 2]]];
Position[list, reffunc]
```

I expected the positions of the first and third are returned but only the third is returned.

[image]

Comment: `Simplify[expr1 == expr2, 0 <= x <= 1/2]`? That simply returns `True`. If that's not what you want, though, then I am not sure that I understand what you would like to happen.

Comment: @MarcoB yes, kind of work for that example  when they have the same domain that would need me to separate the function expression and domains. 
For example I have two functions defined with conditional expression (or include domains). Now I want to make a function returns True if they're same. Like above, you see that expr1 and expr2 are  mathematically same but using SameQ doesn't work as their representations are different.

Comment: You can remove the domain by simply taking only the first part of the answer: `(expr1 == expr2)[[1]]`

Comment: Let me update my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = {ConditionalExpression[Plus[1, Times[-1, x]], 
    Inequality[0, LessEqual, x, LessEqual, Rational[1, 2]]], 
   ConditionalExpression[Plus[1, Times[-1, x]], LessEqual[1, x, 2]], 
   ConditionalExpression[Plus[1, Times[-1, x]], 
    LessEqual[0, x, Rational[1, 2]]]};

reffunc = 
  ConditionalExpression[Plus[1, Times[-1, x]], 
   LessEqual[0, x, Rational[1, 2]]];

pos = Assuming[reffunc[[-1]], Position[list // Simplify, reffunc[[1]]]]

(* {{1}, {3}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `RegionMeasure` of the `ImplicitRegion` of the domains to test if they are equal.

```
ClearAll[conditionalExprMatch]
conditionalExprMatch[expr1_ConditionalExpression, expr2_ConditionalExpression] :=
 With[
  {
   res = expr1 == expr2
   , vars = Variables[First /@ {expr1, expr2}]
   }
  , If[First@res 
    && RegionMeasure@
      ImplicitRegion[
       And @@ MapAt[Not, Map[Last, {expr1, expr2}] , -1]
       , vars
       ] == 0
   , First@res
   , res
   , res
   ]
  ]
```

With

```
{
  expr1 = 
   ConditionalExpression[Plus[1, Times[-1, x]], 
    Inequality[0, LessEqual, x, LessEqual, Rational[1, 2]]]
  , expr2 = 
   ConditionalExpression[Plus[1, Times[-1, x]], 
    LessEqual[0, x, Rational[1, 2]]]
  , expr3 = 
   ConditionalExpression[Plus[1, Times[-1, x]], 
    LessEqual[0, x, Rational[1, 3]]]
  , expr4 = 
   ConditionalExpression[Plus[y, Times[-1, x]], 
    Inequality[0, LessEqual, x, LessEqual, Rational[1, 2]]]
  , expr5 = 
   ConditionalExpression[Plus[y, Times[-1, x]], 
    LessEqual[0, x, Rational[1, 2]]]
  } // Multicolumn
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then

```
conditionalExprMatch[expr1, expr2]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
conditionalExprMatch[expr2, expr3]
```

> [image]

```
conditionalExprMatch[expr3, expr4]
```

> [image]

```
conditionalExprMatch[expr4, expr5]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Hope this helps.